# Laravel cashier (Stripe) - How to create subscription for metered usage?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm having some trouble trying to implement Cashier (Stripe) into my Laravel application.

What I'm trying to do is create a new subscription on an already existing customer (company). But when I do so I get the following error:

```
You cannot set the quantity for metered plans.
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
$company = Company::find(1);    
$company->newSubscription('prod_XXX', 'plan_XXX')->create();
```

In the laravel documentation I found this

```
$user->newSubscription('main', 'premium')->create($paymentMethod);
```

but as far as I understand, if the customer already exists I don't need to pass a paymentMethod in the create() method, since it pairs with the stripe_id in the database.

In case the paymentmethod was required I also tried like this:

```
$company = Company::find(1); 
$paymentMethod = $company->defaultPaymentMethod()->id;
$company->newSubscription('prod_XXX', 'plan_XXX')->create($paymentMethod);
```

But I get the same error message.

In the Stripe dashboard I found this request body in the error log:

```
{
  "expand": {
    "0": "latest_invoice.payment_intent"
  },
  "plan": "plan_XXX",
  "quantity": "1",
  "off_session": "true"
}
```

So the newSubscription() apparently passes a quantity of 1 by default.

So back to my question: How do I create a new metered subscription on an existing customer without passing a quantity?

Comment: Cashier doesn’t really support metered billing: https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/555

Comment: Thank you, I've used the worked around from the issue you posted :)

Answer (score 3):

As Martin Bean commented, Cashier doesn't really support metered billing. In the github issue he linked I found this workaround.

```
$user->newSubscription('default', 'plan_XXX')
     ->quantity(0)
     ->create($request->get('payment_method'));
```

> **EDIT**
>
> Okay, never mind. When I try to update the usage later on to use the
>   correct plan, I get the same error as before :(

Answer (score 1):

for create subscription on metered product using cashier you should implement 2 step:

1. in your controller when subscribe a user: call newsubscription with quantity NULL

   $this->newSubscription('default')
   ->quantity(null)
   ->create();
2. send request stripe for adding usage and increment related item quantity in cashier table.
   [create usage api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create?lang=php)